# Multiple outputs of Matlab ODE solver

Tags: matlab, ode, numerical-integration

I have the following Matlab ODE code:

```
[t,y,~,~,ie] = ode23tb(@(t,y) RHSODE(t,y),[0,t_end], [i0;v0],options);
```

I want the ODE solver could also give me the result z, which is a function of y and dy/dt, such that z = f(y,dy/dt).

Does anyone know how to add such z into the output of the solver?

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do this. The most common, and usually fastest, way is to take advantage of your integration function (`RHSODE` in your case) and evaluate your function `f` after performing the integration. You haven't provided many details with your code but it might look something like this:

```
ydot = RHSODE(t,y);
z = f(y,ydot);
```

where `t` and `y` are the outputs from `ode23tb`.  This requires that both `RHSODE` and `f` be vectorized (or you can wrap the above in a `for` loop).

The other way requires that you create an additional equation (or equations if `z` is a vector) inside of your integration function, `RHSODE`. Normally `ode23tb` integrates anything in this function so `f` must be multiplied by a factor of `t` to cancel this out. Again, your code might look something like this:

```
function ydot = RHSODE(t,y)
ydot0 = ... % Your original ODE(s)
z = f(y,ydot);
ydot = [ydot0;z*t]; % Make column vector
```

Comment: @user2270626: Was this helpful? Did it answer your question? If so, please accept the answer. Thank you.

Comment: But the `y` in `ydot = RHSODE(t,y);` is a whole list of `y` solved from the ode solver. The dimension does not match with the original definition of `y` , say `2 by 1 column vector` in `RHSODE`? How to deal with this problem? @horchler

Comment: If the `y` in `ydot = RHSODE(t,y);` is a scalar, the method works. But if the y in `ydot = RHSODE(t,y);` is say a `2 by 1 column vector`. What should I do?

Comment: @kww: that just means that your integration function isn't vectorized (it doesn't need to be if you're just using `ode45` without needing this solution). As I state in my answer, you can either vectorize it or use a `for` loop to iterate over your outputs. You may need to apply a transpose too depending on your specific code.

Comment: @horcher But there is a problem here. What if an integration failed and solver will call function for previous time step? Do I need to implement output function `outputFcn` that computes the `z` at the initial and all successful steps of the odesolver?

Comment: @horcher In my case `z = f(y,ydot,t)`. `z` is also a function of time. In this case is `outputFcn` that can detect flag and fail steps the only method? Can I use the method in your answer if `z = f(y,ydot,t)`? Thanks for advice.

Comment: @kww: You don't need to worry about failed steps with either of these methods. `ode45` and the other solvers only return output from successful steps. Both of these methods should be more efficient than using an `'OutputFcn'`.

Comment: @horcher thank you. For the second method in your answer here. It seems that it does not work. Say the simplest case of `y` as a scalar so `ydot` has to be a scalar, but in the the second method the output `ydot` is a 2 by 1 column vector. I receive an error from this in the line of ode. Also, should the entry of `ydot` be `z/t` instead?